# How do I get Rookies late in the game?

Tags: xcom-2

This may or may not have been the best course of action, but I prioritized a bunch of other things ahead of Psionics research.  Now that I have a Psi Lab, it apparently works the same way as the GTS, training Rookies to a new psi class.

There's just one problem: I'm all out of Rookies.  When I go to pick up new recruits, at this point they all seem to be Sergeants or Lieutenants.  Is there any way to get more Rookies so I can train them?

Comment: can't you just recruit them normally from the avenger, rather than going to black market/resistance hq?

Comment: @STTLCU I thought I had seen a way to do that, but when I looked around, I can't find it anymore.  Where is the option for that located?

Comment: Oh I do not remember exactly and I can't check now, but probably in the armory you have the chance to do so. Or in Command, maybe? just go through all the options there, i am sure there is a chance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can recruit rookies from inside the Avenger. Click on "Armory", then on "Recruit" and you get a list of wannabe alien killers willing to join your cause for 25§ each.

Answer (score 2):

Another small possibility:

Occasionally small scanning areas will pop up, similar to the ones you can scan for Supply Drops and other resources that will offer recruits. This can occur very rarely in late-game but it is a possibility that can also save you some supplies.